Creating dacpac
I have a requirement to create a .dacpac only with triggers, tables should not be included. Is it possible?
I tried by separating tables & triggers in different folder. I set "Build action" to "None" for tables, but the build failed with an error

SQL71501: Trigger xxx has an unresolved reference to object xxx

Is there a way to achieve this requirement?

A trigger cannot exists on its own, it needs a table

I don't think so - the dacpac is always an all or nothing approach - you get all db objects - you cannot filter on just a specific set of objects. The only alternative I see is to just script out all the triggers into a .sql file from SSMS

"I have a requirement to create a .dacpac only with triggers". Why? Who is giving you that requirement? What are they trying to achieve?
